# usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lexpat

Tags: c++, ld, scons

I am trying compile a software with Scons  I get an error saying,

```
usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lexpat
```

Can you please tell me how can I fix it? Thank you very much.  Here's the full error message:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
We're on a 64-bit machine
use 32-bit libs & executables even on 64 bit system
OSNAME = Linux-x86_64-32
No installation being done

scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o src/examples/.Linux-x86_64-32/dana -m32 src/examples/.Linux-x86_64-32/dana.o -Lsrc/libsrc/.Linux-x86_64-32 -Lsrc/libsrc -Lsrc/libsrc++/.Linux-x86_64-32 -Lsrc/libsrc++ -levioxx -levio -lpthread -lexpat -lz -ldl -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lexpat
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [src/examples/.Linux-x86_64-32/dana] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Comment: can you show the code which generates error?

Comment: It looks like you need to install some 32-bit development libraries. On Debian or Ubuntu, you probably need to install the `libexpat1-dev:i386` package.

Comment: On RHEL derivatives you need to install `expat.i686` and `compat-expat1.i686`. These provides the library `libexpat.so` versions 2 and 1 respectively.

Comment: Than you so much. It works for me after I install libexpat.so.

Answer (score 1):

Below solution worked with me on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo apt install libexpat-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem in Fedora 34. Doing

```
sudo yum install expat-devel
```

will solve the problem.

Comment: "I have heard" and "I am trying" sounds like you've posted an answer without knowing if this works.